# How to download the image from URL array and append it to an array one by one Swift

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I try to download the image from the URL array and append the image to the image array for my collection view. But it does not download and append it to the image array one by one. So I try to use dispatch group, But not working. What is the correct way to add Dispatch group?

```
func downloadPhoto(){
    progressImgArray.removeAll() // this is the image array
    for i in 0..<progressArray.count{
        let urls = URL(string: progressArray[i].userProgressImage) // this is the URL array
        let group = DispatchGroup()

        print(urls ?? "nil image")
        print("-------GROUP ENTER-------")

        group.enter()
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urls!, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

            print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? urls?.lastPathComponent ?? "nil image")

            if let imgData = data {
                if UIImage(data: imgData) != nil {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                        self.progressImgArray.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)
                    }
                }
            }

            group.leave()
        }).resume()

        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

PRINTED: the sequence is wrong

```
http://sweat.asia/app/users_progresses/users_progresses_111_761319316286fcb38a0b.png
-------GROUP ENTER-------
http://sweat.asia/app/users_progresses/users_progresses_111_263983427965d44f5021.png
-------GROUP ENTER-------
http://sweat.asia/app/users_progresses/users_progresses_111_3361893721fa8f84015a.png
-------GROUP ENTER-------
users_progresses_111_263983427965d44f5021.png
users_progresses_111_761319316286fcb38a0b.png
users_progresses_111_3361893721fa8f84015a.png
```

How to make it like this

```
http://sweat.asia/app/users_progresses/users_progresses_111_761319316286fcb38a0b.png
    -------GROUP ENTER-------
users_progresses_111_761319316286fcb38a0b.png

http://sweat.asia/app/users_progresses/users_progresses_111_263983427965d44f5021.png
    -------GROUP ENTER-------
users_progresses_111_263983427965d44f5021.png

...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that `group.notify` will block until the dispatch group is empty. But you fill it with three "enters" before any of the "leaves" are called so the "notify" doesn't happen until the third "leave" happens.

Instead "notify" you need to use "wait". And to use "wait" you need to put the whole thing in a new background thread.

The updated code should be something like the following:

```
func downloadPhoto(){
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        progressImgArray.removeAll() // this is the image array

        for i in 0..<progressArray.count {
            guard let url = URL(string: progressArray[i].userProgressImage) else {
                continue
            }

            let group = DispatchGroup()

            print(url)
            print("-------GROUP ENTER-------")

            group.enter()
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? url.lastPathComponent)

                if let imgData = data, let image = UIImage(data: imgData) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                        self.progressImgArray.append(image)
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }
                } else if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }

                group.leave()
            }).resume()

            group.wait()
        }
    }
}
```

I've also made several other improvements including better handling of optionals.

Comment: Simply The Best. Answer for this type of problem ..!

Answer (score 1):

**A Small update to rmaddy's answer :**

> Get Notified when array is full with downloaded images.

```
func downloadImageFromUrl()
{
    DispatchQueue.global().async
        {
            self.imageArray.removeAll()
            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

            for i in 0..<(self.imageUrlArray?.count)!
            {
                guard let url = URL(string: (self.imageUrlArray?![i])!)
                    else{ continue }

                dispatchGroup.enter()
                Alamofire.request(url).responseData(completionHandler: { response in

                    guard
                        let data = response.result.value,
                        let image = UIImage(data:data)
                        else {
                            print("Error in downlaoding images : ",(response.error?.localizedDescription)!)
                            return
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.imageArray.append(image)
                    }
                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                })
                dispatchGroup.wait()
            }
            dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main,execute: {
                print("are we done.... :",self.imageArray.count)
                self.yourCollection.reloadData()
            })
    }
}
```

> I mean for me it is really working like a charm, I've a tableview in **which one of the cell of tableview contains Collection View**